# package-install tries a URL whose content is not found

Tags: package

I want to install the package running:

```
M-x package-install RET markdown-mode RET
```

And I get the following error

```
package-install-from-archive: https://melpa.org/packages/markdown-mode-20180904.1601.el: Not found
```

Which is true, since doing via Firefox I get 404 error.

I have the following version of Emacs:

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK + Version 3.22.30)
  of 2018-07-05
```

How can I install it?

Comment: try `package-refresh-contents` then `package-install` as I see version:   20181112.1529 in my refreshed buffer...

Comment: Thank you.

I followed your instructions and it worked correctly.
I was able to install the package I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trying to download an older version of the package. Emacs keeps a cache the list of available package versions on every command, to save time and bandwidth. It refreshes the list when you open the package list with `M-x list-packages` or when you press <kbd>r</kbd> (`package-menu-refresh`) on the list. If you use `M-x package-install` directly, you may need to refresh the list manually with `M-x package-refresh-contents` before calling `package-install`.